# Sorted shared Mailbox or Bus for a pool of Akka actors?

Tags: algorithm, scala, sorting, concurrency, akka

I'm trying to learn Scala and Akka at the same time and it's amazing but it is also slightly confusing sometimes, I'm sorry for the fragmentation of my question.

I understand the actor model. There are actors, they send and receive messages, they have a Mailbox to store received messages, a Mailbox can prioritize messages, and then everything becomes confusing.

I've been reading a lot and the more I read the more confused I am, so I hope someone can provide some help to reduce confusion levels to an acceptable minimum. Pointers are welcome but I may need some small glue explanation to put everything together, basically some help to RTFM.

Questions are:

1. How can messages be sorted in the inbox? I've read about "implicits" (in ordered Mailboxes) but that sounds like magic. I thought sorted Mailboxes would only accept types that implement the `Comparable` interface but here Scala uses the functional paradigm and accepts an `ordering` function if I'm not mistaken, which returns an `Ordering[T]`. However the ordering function (working on `T`?) may be restricted to comparable objects, so, back to `Comparable`?
2. Is there any possibility of sharing a Mailbox?
3. Should some implementation of a Bus be used here? Can a bus be sorted?
4. What is an `implicit abstract def`? It looks like a method that should be implemented (`abstract`) but that does not need to be implemented (`implicit`), that sounds like a contradiction. (This is a definition in `SortedSet`)
5. Should I define a `Dispatcher`? I haven't been able to figure out how does that match in the whole architecture. But I keep searching for pools and finding dispatchers instead.
6. Should I read about `Future`s? I'm trying to make a small implementation to grasp concepts gradually, in a loop of reading and programming. So sorry again for so many questions.

The solution I've thought so far consists on:

1. having an Actor that is the central node for communication.
2. This central Actor keeps a `SortedSet` where the messages that are to be dispatched to the pool of actors are enqueued
3. This central actor keeps as well a `Set` of Actors that are free.
4. When an Actor is free (after handling any message) the free actor sends a message to the central actor asking for some work to do.
5. The central actor processes the message:

   1. if there is work pending, it dequeues the message that needs to be processed.
   2. if there is no work to do, the reference to the free agent is stored to send him some job.
6. The central actor processes messages with job tasks analogously.

   1. if there are free actors then the job is sent to a free actor.
   2. if there are not free actors then the job is added to the `SortedSet`.
7. the pool of actors is created by simply creating them and sending all their references to the central manager.

I have thought of this solution because I have not a good knowledge of Scala nor Akka. But I would not like to be stuck with this type of solutions for ever. Basically an actor can do anything, but I'd like to use them properly and using properly all other elements as mailboxes, buses, pools, dispatchers, futures, etc.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I see the votes to close the question are accumulating. Should I split it into several different questions? (I think the context is important) What is the problem with the question in the way it is now? Thank you and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: There's just too much going on here question wise. Try breaking things up into smaller pieces in an effort to get the total set if information you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 1 & 2 & 5: Akka's documentation on dispatchers explains pretty well what a dispatcher is and how to define and use one. It also documents mailboxes, how you can define your own, potentially prioritized mailbox and how multiple actors can share a single mailbox:
  http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.4/java/dispatchers.html
- 3: AFAIK, the default `EventBus` in Akka, does not allow sorting messages
- 4: `implicit abstract def` defines an `abstract` method which is also `implicit`. Implicits and abstract members are orthogonal concepts, so there's no contradiction here. Maybe you want to define an implicit conversion and to delegate its implementation to a subclass.
- 6: Yes, futures are an important part, not just in Akka, but for Scala concurrency in general.

Regarding your particular design problem, maybe a simpler solution would be to use a router. Routers are special actors which dispatch incoming messages to its registered routees according to a policy.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.4/scala/routing.html

In your case you would replace your central actor with a router. If your messages need to be prioritized you can configure a priority mailbox for that router.

A router which gets close to the behavior you are describing would be the [SmallestMailboxRouter](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.4/scala/routing.html#SmallestMailboxRouter).

If you do decide you need to use a central actor which accumulates messages, take great care when it comes to the supervision of this actor. By default failing actors are restarted, so you may end up losing the `SortedSet` that holds your messages. That's another reason to use a customized mailbox: you decouple the actor state from the message ordering semantics.

Comment: Also, it is somewhat confusing to think in terms of "sorting" in a concurrent environment. It is more like prioritizing.